# Why no speed up with parallel using boot.ci to get BCa confidence intervals?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, statistics-bootstrap

The bottom of the answer in this question ([Calculating CIs of fixed effects using confint in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613479/calculating-cis-of-fixed-effects-using-confint-in-r)) suggests one should see `user` time > `elapsed` time when parallel works. Despite specifying `parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 4` when running `boot.ci` I don't see that result. Also, I only see about 30% CPU load in Mac's Activity Monitor as it runs. Does this mean I'm not parallel processing with my 4-core iMac? If not, any advice on getting it to work?

Here's an example:

```
library(car)
library(boot)
set.seed(47)

 y <- rgamma(2000, 2)
 x1 <- 3 * y + rnorm(2000)
 x2 <- y^2 + rnorm(2000)
 x3 <- rnorm(2000)
 MyData <- data.frame(c(y, x1, x2, x3))
 MyModel <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = MyData)
# Boot doesn't have a parallel option that I know of
 system.time(BootModel <- Boot(MyModel, R = 3000))
#-----------------------
   user  system elapsed 
 10.164   1.086  11.263 
#-----------------------

# calculate CIs for a single coefficient
# boot.ci has a parallel option, but the sys.time results are the same
system.time(ConfBoot <- boot.ci(BootModel, level = c(.90, .95, .99), type = "bca", 
            index = 2, parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 4))
#-----------------------
   user  system elapsed 
 19.698   0.367  20.162
```

On a related note, why does boot.ci take so long to compute the BCa confidence intervals? My reading of the code is that `bca.ci` takes the existing replicates from `boot.out` for its calculations, so it doesn't seem like it should take so much longer to run than `boot` does (via `Boot` in this example).